# How to avoid rewrite and redirection loop in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying this code in my .htaccess file but for some reason when I try a file `/1.html` in browser, it enters into redirection loop requesting `/1` again and again.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

I have gone through apache documentation and only got that apache can restart processing rewrite rules in some cases. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both rules are doing opposites and will indeed cause infinite looping. To fix you need one redirect rule based on `THE_REQUEST` variable, as it represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```